# How to download a file if filename contains space or %20

Tags: android

I am able to download file using URL Connection but if my filename contains space or %20 then i am unable to download file.

Here is my code..

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this, R.style.startdialog);
        pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_downloader);
        progressCircle = (DonutProgress) pDialog.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgress);
        progressCircle.setFinishedStrokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        progressCircle.setUnfinishedStrokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.hint_color));
        progressCircle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        progressCircle.setProgress(0);

        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mediapath + f_url[0].substring(f_url[0].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;



    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        progressCircle.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

**Asynk task Execution**

```
new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(urlString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 try {
    String urlString = "url string";
    URL url = new URL(urlString.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));

    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
    connection.connect();



} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It is not a best way because there are a lot of other `%..` symbols which may cause problems in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get your `f_url`? Seems it is malformed. You have to separate `f_url` to `protocol`, `host` and `path`, encode `path` with

```
String encodedPath = Uri.encode(path);
```

and build uri back with

```
URL url = new URL(protocol, host, encodedPath)
```

or with other appropriate [URL class constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html?is-external=true).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replaceAll("","")` method and then try it again like the following:

```
String replaceURL=s1.replaceAll(" ","%20");
```